# >Parsing varying REST response in PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell

I have a REST response which sets a variable as shown below:

> PS H:> echo $response
>
> Success
>
> -------                                                                                                                                            @{count=1; uri=https://server/results/Success}

I can also do:

> PS H:> echo $response.Success.uri
>
> https://server/results/Success

I need the uri. However it may possibly at times be on $response.Fail.uri or $response.Error.uri instead of $response.Success.uri

Must all the variants be check in PowerShell separately or is there a way to extract uri regardless of Fail, Response or Success ?

EDIT:

> PS H:> Write-Host $response | fl * -f
>
> @{Success=}

Comment: Take a look at the output using `$response | fl * -f` and see whether the uri is present on a top level.

Comment: No it's not on the top level (see edit)

Comment: So the answer is probably no. But if you give us access to the ressource we can check it.

Comment: It's not a public resource so (physically) unable to grant access.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$response | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "*" | Select-Object uri
```

This assumes a few things about your response structure, but might help steer you down the right path!